# explode() in PHP

Tags: php, explode

I have used the explode function in PHP to break up a string into an array giving "," as the separator to break the string. My question is, what if the string does not contain the "," separator "," ? will there be an error or will the string be treated as an array with a single element?

Comment: Why not try out yourself? It's the latter though

Comment: We don't you just try it? It takes like 10 seconds to test this.

Comment: @Pekka you couldn't resist, huh? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it would be very easy to test, I'll just show the output.

```
php -r 'print_r(explode(",", "this is a test"));'
Array
(
    [0] => this is a test
)
```

Answer (score 3):

From [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

> If delimiter contains a value that is
>   not contained in string and a negative
>   limit is used, then an empty array
>   will be returned

Answer (score 0):

You could also use regex split if they use delimiters such as ; and ", "

Comment: yeah, but that seems to be slower than explode

Comment: but it allows for more things.